# How to set global properties in adobe cq5

Tags: adobe, aem

I'm developing components on adobe cq5 and need some help/advice. I would like to create a phone number component part of which uses phone number prefixes. I want a page author to be able to set the range of prefixes (i.e. they need to be content managed), but I don’t want them to have to re-specify this list every time they add a phone number component. The list of prefixes needs to be globally maintained not component level properties. I know how to set and use component level properties but not global ones. Can someone tell me how or point me in the right direction of an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about using **design dialog** instead of edit dialog? This can solve your problem. [There](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21056881/1675951) is some info regarding this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the creation of a dialog is that you are assigning a `name` which provides the dialog the understanding of where you want to store the values.

This is usually in the form of `./foo` what people forget is that the `name` field is a path specification. You could equally specify a name of `/global/data/phoneprefixes` which would provide the feature that you are looking for.

To then use this data, from your code, you would need to look in the same place. The properties object wouldn't have it at this point since it's only providing the relational properties of the resource you're on.

Comment: I tried this, but couldn't get it to work. I'd add values to the dialog and the next time I opened it they would be gone. So I think I must have done something wrong with the name...?

Comment: There's a couple of possibilities. I would check the write permissions for the person who is performing the changes in the dialog. To make sure that they have write access to that path. Additionally, you want to make sure that the parent path exists to where you are putting the property.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use design dialog for any reason i think the other option could be using the Reference component.

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/author/page-authoring/default-components/editmode.html#Reference